# Matplotlib : log-scale not showing minor ticks

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code.

```
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()

data = np.loadtxt('datalog.txt')
xdata=data[:,0]; ydata=data[:,1]
ax1.plot(xdata,ydata)
ax1.set_xscale('log')
plt.savefig('plot.png')
plt.show()
```

This gives the following plot.

[image]

Why am I not getting the minor ticks that one usually expects?

File `datalog.txt` can be found [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=62828743337749347151).